# Wu formula for $\mathbb{Z}_N$ classes

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, characteristic-classes

Let $w_1\in H^1(M, \mathbb{Z}_2)$ be the Stiefel-Whitney class of the tangent bundle of d-dimensional manifold $M$, and $x_{d-1}\in H^{d-1}(M, \mathbb{Z}_2)$. Wu formula tells us 
$$Sq^1 x_{d-1}= u_1\cup  x_{d-1}= w_1 \cup x_{d-1}$$
where $u_1$ is the first Wu-class.

Now, let $x_{d-1}\in H^{d-1}(M, \mathbb{Z}_N)$ for even $N$. Then we consider
the Bockstein: $\beta: H^{d-1}(M, \mathbb{Z}_N)\to H^{d}(M, \mathbb{Z}_2)$. (When $N=2$, $Sq^1=\beta$. $\beta$ is a generalization of $Sq^1$ in the general $N$ case.)

The question is: whether there is a version of Wu formula for 
$$\beta x_{d-1}=?$$
for general even $N$?

Comment: Where are you getting your Bockstein from? The picture I'm used to is you have a short exact sequence of groups $G\to H\to G/H$ and then the map goes $H^n(-;G/H) \to H^{n+1}(-;G)$. Are you using the sequence $\mathbb{Z}_2 \to \mathbb{Z}_{2N} \to \mathbb{Z}_N$? I think also you have a typo in the degrees, the target of your Bockstein should have degree $d$.

Comment: @William thanks for comment. Yes, I am using the sequence you mentioned. The typo is corrected.